# Alternatives for the Emerging Hot Spot Analysis/Mann-Kendall statistic (less than 10 time steps)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, spatial-statistics, spatio-temporal-data

I came across ESRI's [Emerging Hot Spot Analysis (Space Time Pattern Mining toolbox)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/space-time-pattern-mining/emerginghotspots.htm) and really like what it does. Unfortunately for me, it relies on the Mann-Kendall statistic which apparently needs a minimum of ten time steps to run the analysis. I have less than ten time steps.

I was wondering if anyone knew of an alternative analysis that can be used with fewer than ten time steps?

I can execute the analysis in ArcGIS Desktop or in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Emerging Hot Spot Analysis tool does not use a Kendal statistic but, rather a space-time variant of the Getis-Ord Gi* to identify space-time clusters. The Kendal Tau is for analysis of temporal correlation and monotonic trend. If you want the Kendal Tau I have both a time-series vector and raster implementation in the spatialEco R package but, remember the minimum observation problem still holds. Your underlying question here is basically "what time-series statistics can I use with small a *n*". The answer is really, none.

It is analogous to trying to make an inference about spatial process when there is no spatial autocorrelation in your data. It is a power issue and you really do need a minimal number of observations. You could just try a linear model but your power and significance will be very low and, if not independent through time, you may not meet iid assumption. Unfortunately, due to the reasons stated above something like an AR or ARIMA model are out of the question and have even higher data requirements in the length of the time-series. I am not sure how power issues come into play in space-time SCAN statistics but you may be able to overcome the small sample issue by putting a SCAN model into a Monte Carlo analysis.